# keep getting strange message when running VB6 Package and Deployment Wizard

Tags: installation, vb6, package

I have gigabytes of room and all permissions on the target folder.

**Package and Deployment Wizard**

> An unknown error occurred while building the cabinet file 'xxx.cab'. Please verify that you have proper access to the destination and that there is sufficient space there to create the file.

Comment: You might want to check https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196583.  Looks like the only resolution that might apply to you is the temp folder issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ran CCleaner and manually cleaned my temp folders. What solved it was creating a new folder for the install files to go into.